# How to use ngnix proxy_pass with URI?

Tags: server-side

My goal is redirect one domain to another using ngnix:

http://abc.mydomain1.com     ->  http://mydomain2.com:8080/test1

I tried the following:

```
 server {
      listen   80;
      server_name  abc.mydomain1.com;
      access_log off;
      location / {
           proxy_pass http://mydomain2.com:8080/test1/;
           proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
           proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           port_in_redirect off;
           proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      }
     # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
 #
 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 } }
```

It works with the first page index.html however this page needs to load javascripts and css resources and viewing the source code I notice that all links are generated like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

How to avoid contextPath "test1"? I think something is missing in the header but I don't know what :(

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach was incorrect because the server http://mydomain2.com:8080/test1/ will generate the links based in the context in this case "test1". Therefore ngnix is working good.

I resolved the problem creating virtual host in http://mydomain2.com:8080 for "test1"

```
 <Host name="abc.mydomain1.com"  appBase="abc.mydomain1.com"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"></Host>
```

and I changed my redirection to (removing test1):

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name  abc.mydomain1.com;
  access_log off;
  location / {
       proxy_pass http://mydomain2.com:8080/;
       proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
       proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       port_in_redirect off;
       proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  }
 # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
 #
 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
 root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 } }
```